# Image loading using picasso on disk

Tags: android, caching, android-image, picasso

I am using Picasso.

I want to cache images on disk and I am using okhttpdownloader for it.

Here is what I am trying to do I want Image to be cached on either external sd card or phone memory but don't want to cache images on heap memory due to memory constraints. So if image is loaded for first time it should be cached on disk and when next time request is made for same url it should look into disk first if it is cached or not.

I am not able to achieve this following is my code.

```
public class PicassoCache {

/**
 * Static Picasso Instance
 */
private static Picasso picassoInstance = null;
private File cacheDir;

/**
 * PicassoCache Constructor
 *
 * @param context application Context
 */
private PicassoCache (Context context) {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = context.getExternalCacheDir();
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    Downloader downloader   = new OkHttpDownloader(cacheDir, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
    builder.downloader(downloader);

    picassoInstance = builder.build();
}

/**
 * Get Singleton Picasso Instance
 *
 * @param context application Context
 * @return Picasso instance
 */
public static Picasso getPicassoInstance (Context context) {

    if (picassoInstance == null) {

        new PicassoCache(context);
        return picassoInstance;
    }

    return picassoInstance;
}

}
```

and inside Adapter I have following code

```
 PicassoCache.getPicassoInstance(context)
                .load(item.imageUrl)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .into(holder.itemImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing 
`.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)`
 and adding NO_STORE to memoryPolicy
`.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)`

Comment: this works but still I see there is increase used heap memory when I scroll up and down.

Comment: I'm not an expert with respect to the consumption of heap space, however a temporary increase may be normal behavior due to the loading of bitmaps from disk to memory. As I understand, the big problem is **only when and if** the heap size is not stable over medium time, that maybe you have a memory leak, that maybe garbage collection is ineffective to free up memory.